# Windows Live Contacts API, 2 Applications in one domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, contacts, live, windows-live

We have 2 applications in 1 domain. one is in the root and the other is in a subdirectory (www.domain.com and www.domain.com/app2).

We're using Windows Live API to import email contacts into both of our applications.

But the issue is that Windows Live only allows one domain to be used even if we created 2 API keys for the 2 apps.

Is there a solution for this. I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.
I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 just in case you it might help.